Add a form field dynamically with Symfony UX
I want to add a dynamic field in a form. However, when clicking on the concerned field, nothing happens. Indeed, when clicking on the "Can publish a podcast" field, another field should normally appear.
The project configuration uses Webpack Encore with Symfony 7.
Here are the main codes:
The live component :
<?php

namespace App\Twig\Components;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\DefaultActionTrait;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\LiveAction;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\ComponentWithFormTrait;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\AsLiveComponent;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

#[AsLiveComponent]
final class Authorisation extends AbstractController
{
    use ComponentWithFormTrait;
    use DefaultActionTrait;

    protected function instantiateForm(): FormInterface
    {
        $user = new User();
        // Création du formulaire dynamique pour ajout des champs dynamique dans la page de traitement de la demande
        return $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    }
}

The form type
<?php

namespace App\Form;

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfonycasts\DynamicForms\DependentField;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfonycasts\DynamicForms\DynamicFormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder = new DynamicFormBuilder($builder); // Rendre le builder dynamique et interactif

        $builder
         //.....
            ->add('authorisations', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Les autorisations accordées:',
                'mapped' => false,
                'choices' => [
                    'Can write an article' => 1,
                    'Can publish a podcast' => 2
                ],
                'label_attr' => [
                    'id' => 'labelAuthorisations',
                ],
                // Rendre le champs "authorisations" de type checkbox
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true
            ])
            // Rendre le champs "authorisations" dynamique et interactif
            ->addDependent('podcasts', 'authorisations', function (DependentField $field, ?array $authorisations) {
                
                if ($authorisations !== null && in_array(2, $authorisations)) {                    
                    $field->add(TextType::class, [
                        'mapped' => false,
                        "label" => "Sous-categorie"
                    ]);
                }
            });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}

The component twig (the view)
<div{{attributes}}>
    <!-- component html -->
    {{ form_start(form)}}
    {{ form_row(form.authorisations)}}
    {% if form.podcasts is defined %}
        {{ form_row(form.podcasts) }}
        <p>hello</p>
    {% endif %}
    <div id="inputsSubmit">
        <input type="submit" value="Refuser" class="secondaryButton" data-live-action-param="save" data-action="live#action:prevent">
        <input type="submit" value="Accepter" class="primaryButton">
        {{ form_end(form, {render_rest: false})}}</div>

The component import
        <twig:Authorisation/>

Nothing appears when I tried With Webpack Encore, but without Webpack it works well.

When you run with Webpack Encore, do you build the assets first?

Yes I built first before manipulating the view
